# Why is this grammar giving me a "non LL(*) decision" error?

Tags: antlr, antlrworks

I am trying to add support for expressions in my grammar. I am following the example given by [Scott Stanchfield's Antlr Tutorial](http://javadude.com/articles/antlr3xtut/). For some reason the add rule is causing an error. It is causing a non-LL(*) error saying, "Decision can match input such as "'+'..'-' IDENT" using multiple alternatives"

Simple input like:

```
a.b.c + 4
```

causes the error. I am using the AntlrWorks Interpreter to test my grammar as I go. There seems to be a problem with how the tree is built for the unary +/- and the add rule. I don't understand why there are two possible parses.

Here's the grammar:

```
path    :   (IDENT)('.'IDENT)* //(NAME | LCSTNAME)('.'(NAME | LCSTNAME))*
    ;

term    :   path
    |   '(' expression ')'
    |   NUMBER
    ;

negation 
    :   '!'* term
    ;

unary   :   ('+' | '-')* negation

    ;

mult    :   unary (('*' | '/' | '%') unary)*
    ;

add     :   mult (( '+' | '-' ) mult)*
    ;

relation 
    :   add (('==' | '!=' | '<' | '>' | '>=' | '<=') add)*
    ;

expression
    :   relation (('&&' | '||') relation)*
    ;

multiFunc   
    :   IDENT expression+
    ;

NUMBER  :   DIGIT+ ('.'DIGIT+)?
    ;

IDENT   :   (LCLETTER|UCLETTER)(LCLETTER|UCLETTER|DIGIT|'_')*
    ;

COMMENT
        :       '//' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? '\n' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    |       '/*' ( options {greedy=false;} : . )* '*/' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
        ;

WS  :   (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' | '\f')+ {$channel = HIDDEN;}
    ;

fragment
LCLETTER 
    :   'a'..'z'
    ;

fragment
UCLETTER:   'A'..'Z'
    ;   

fragment
DIGIT   :   '0'..'9'
    ;
```

I need an extra set of eyes. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you let one or more expressions match in:

```
multiFunc   
 : IDENT expression+
 ;
```

makes your grammar ambiguous. Let's say you're trying to match `"a 1 - - 2"` using the `multiFunc` rule. The parser now has 2 possible ways to parse this: `a` is matched by `IDENT`, but the 2 minus signs `1 - - 2` cause trouble for `expression+`. The following 2 parses are possible:

### parse 1

[image]

### parse 2

[image]

Comment: Ahhh! That makes sense. I'll have to figure out a different way to create parameter lists. Thanks! By the way the graphs you provided helped a bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar in rule `multiFunc` has a list of expressions. An expression can begin with `+` or `-` on behalf of `unary`, thus due to the list, it can also be followed by the same tokens. This is in conflict with the `add` rule: there is a problem deciding between continuation and termination.